# Excel help. If column A or column B have values copy value to column C

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to combine columns from column A and B int column C as such.

[image: Click here for picture]

I tried this in C

```
=IF(A2,A2,B2)
```

Comment: What if both have values?

Comment: can you show how you've tried to do this? (i.e. formulas, macro)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! We are _not_ a code-writing service. Please check out the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting questions.

Comment: Looks like the OP is trying to avoid a 0 where B1 is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this simple formula in C1:

```
=A1 & B1
```

Or:

```
=IF(A1<>"",A1,B1)
```

If you only want the one return.

Comment: Thank you very much